# Does page-fault occur when Operating System reads a file for the first time?

Tags: operating-system

Hello OS experts from Stackoverflow.

I have been struggling to find out whether the page-fault occurs when the OS reads a file for the first time in Intel architecture x86.

I am curious about how the Operating system will handle after the userspace application calls the read syscall after the open syscall.

For my understanding...

1. After the read system call, the kernel accesses an invalid page of the page table that is not currently mapped by the memory management unit and raises the page-fault.
2. The page fault will call for demand paging. The Kernel looks up the disk address of the desired page and schedules disk operation (I/O scheduling).

**However, I received a tip from my advisor that the page-fault does not occur when the file is opened and read for the first time.**

Is this true? I've been searching all over to find a clear answer to this without any success. Would it be possible to explain whether the page-fault happens or not at the first file read?

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon how the file is being read. If the file is being read as a memory mapped file, it is close to a certainty that a page fault will occur.

If being read through a buffer, its is likely the system will require the buffer to be locked in memory. However, there could be a page file when transferring the data to a user buffer.